# How to start new activity on button click in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to go from one activity to another when clicking the 'Login' button, here is my code for button click-

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(id.getText().toString().equals("ajay")&&pass.getText().toString().equals("sainy"))
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,adminhome.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

                }
                else if(id.getText().toString().equals("aj")&&pass.getText().toString().equals("sa"))
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userhome.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);                 
                }
                else
                    res.setText("Incorrect Credentials...Retry");
            }
        });
```

but when I enter correct credentials 'adminhome' or 'userhome' activity is not starting.
The same 'MainActivity' is opening again. I think I have problem in following code -

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,adminhome.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

or in,

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,userhome.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

What is the problem? Please help, I am learning android.

Comment: What if the other activities have the same layout and you are mistaken? check setContentView in the other activities

Comment: Try starting intents like this:

Intent i = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),adminhome.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: Classes that does not start with uppercase letter.. Is that made on purpose?

Comment: Are your activities declared in manifest? What do you get? Is it a crash, or just does nothing? Are you sure the correct if statement was true when you entered the credentials?

Comment: @SherifelKhatib - Yes, it helped. I had to change the contentView. Thankyou very much.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Good spot.  Well done.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib write an answer so Ajay can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the comments, but anyway, when anyone of you encounters such behavior:

- Make sure the other activities do not have the same layout, and, so, you will think that the same activity is being open when it is the other activity. Just double check the layout of the activities.

Answer (score 0):

you can check and see if the new activity is put inside the manifest or not, as i did below

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.hossa.multitask.activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the View.OnClickListener interface and override the onClick method.

```
ImageView btnWatchVideo;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search1);
        ImageView btnSearch = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSearch: {
                Intent intent = new 
             Intent(Search.this,SearchFeedActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }
}
```